# How to convert a finished project in QGIS to PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf

I have finished my project and need to convert it into a PDF file. How can I do it?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this... BTW... I'm a longtime ESRI ArcGIS user and I just downloaded QGIS (I hadn't seen it in a few years). I'm loving it! Although I need to get more familiar with it.. I've been searching the web any time I have a relatively simple question. The last search I did revealed how to use the python window to consume ArcGIS REST services.. Pretty Cool!

Comment: Is it possible to export your QGIS-Project in PDF 'with Layers'? Like it is possible with ESRI ArcGIS where you can switch between Layers while you have only a "one-sheet-PDF"?! Thanks for any help! :-)

Comment: Is this a new question? If so please post it as a separate question and not as an answer to someone else's.

Answer (score 11):

*I'm going to answer this but you should really do a quick search first before asking something like this, or at least have a look though the manuals at: http://www.qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html*

If you want a PDF you need to first create a composer window, `File->New Print Composer..`.  Once you have a new print composer you can add a map (`Layer->Add Map..`) and add it by dragging an area in the composer.

You can then export the composer to PDF using `File->Export to PDF..`

Comment: I have to Export to SVG from QGIS (then load into Adobe Illustrator) to get the layers out (just have to create layers and re-name) if QGIS supported Layered PDF then can eliminate the illustrator steps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Qgis, in versions prior to 3.0, does not export the PDF into Layers, only in bitmap. In version 3.0, the user can export in PDF as it does in AcGis. The QGis has evolved satisfactorily in this latest version. He has solved many bugs and is leaving the composer with an interesting quality.